# using a number in laravel query builder where statement returns correct response but wrong response when variable containing a number is used

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datatable, laravel-5.6

I am generating a query based on available parameters from the view. But when i add the $request parameters to the query it still returns all rows

This is a laravel 5.6 project. When I use an actual number, say 1, in my where clause directly I get a correct result but when I use the request variable it returns a wrong result

```
//This is the query variable

    $all_students = DB::table('student_reports')
    ->leftJoin('students', 'student_reports.student_id', '=', 'students.id')
            ->leftJoin('classes', 'student_reports.class_id', '=', 'classes.id')
     ->when($request->has('class_id'), function($data) use ($request){
            return $data->where('student_reports.class_id', $request->class_id);
     });

//The condition for when returns true and the value for $request->class_id is a number
```

but when I do

```
->where('student_reports.class_id', 2)
```

I get a correct result

Comment: Does `$request->class_id` hold the value you expect it to?

Comment: dump `$request->class_id` and post what does it return

Answer (score 0):

try, maybe help this

```
$classId= $request->input('class_id');

->when($classId, function($data, $classId) {
        return $data->where('student_reports.class_id', $classId);
 });
```